# How to find last and first entry in cassandra (date is part of partition key)

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible to find first and last entry in Cassandra database if my partition key contains text date as a part of partition key to avoid large partitions?

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
    stockexchange text,
    symbol text,
    ts timestamp,
    date text,
    tid text,
    price decimal,
    side text,
    size decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY ((stockexchange, symbol, date), ts, tid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC, tid ASC)
```

Comment: Show your data model

Comment: @AshrafulIslam, added

Comment: First and Last entry of a specific partition key ?

Comment: i've updated model with date.
want to find the first entry of stockexchange and symbol, but i don't know the day, that's why i cant choose partition

Comment: You can't find the first entry and last entry of stockexchange and symbol with this data model. Because cassandra don't order data by partition. You have to maintain another table to track first and last date

Comment: thanks, so looks like cassandra is not ready for time series data in my case
one the one hand you will come across with the large partitions, on the other hand you are unable to search through the partitions

Comment: can keep a 2nd table with ((stockexchange, symbol), date) to lookup the current and a list of existing dates for a symbol.

Comment: i've heard about that trick, but i'm not sure, will it be maintainable or not

Comment: If you know all the fields of partition key, you can order by both ts and tid in ASC and get limit 1, you will get the first entry. If you order by ts and tid in DESC in limit 1, you can get the latest entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one solution is - to create the second table and store separately.
only: stockexchange, symbol, timestamp

This gives you ability to find the first and last timestamp by your key (stockexchange:symbol)

Please pay attention, that you have to store the data in the same moment and Cassandra is not ACID database type.

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
    stockexchange text,
    symbol text,
    ts timestamp,
    date text,
    tid text,
    price decimal,
    side text,
    size decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY ((stockexchange, symbol, date), ts, tid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC, tid ASC)

CREATE TABLE trades_timestampts (
stockexchange text,
symbol text,
tid text,
ts timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((stockexchange, symbol), ts, tid)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts asc, tid asc);
```